# Integrating a .exe file into a visual studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

broken to bare-bones scene: 
I have a program in c# that calls a .exe inside cmd(using process.start), passing some required arguments.

What i'm trying to do: Include the exe into the project so that i don't have to call cmd.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to include so you don't have to ship two files then just include it into the project as "embedded resource" (see project item options) and then you can call ResourceManager.GetStream and write it to file and call Process.Start.

If you want integrate the functions of that exe so that the exe is not needed anymore (no Process.Start) then you need the source code...

EDIT:
the "write to file" is not necessary if the exe is .NET - then you can directly load it from the resource stream as Assembly/AppDomin and execute it.

Comment: Yes, but you make "write it to file" sound so easy. It's not. You have to make sure that you're writing the file somewhere where the program's context *always* has read/write privileges. In practice, it's difficult to ensure that. That means you're stuck writing the EXE to the "Temp" folder, or your app breaks. It's far better to distribute the EXE as a standalone dependency. You're *still* going to have to "call cmd" once you extract it, so this is all pretty pointless.

Comment: you are right - for native exe. BUT if is a .NET exe you don't have to write it to a file at all - you can just load + execute it as via AppDomain/Assembly from a stream...

Comment: How will you do it using AppDomain/Assembly if its' in .NET?. I am a newbie.

Comment: Call AppDomain.CreateDomain and then .Load ().. in Load you put the byte array of the assembly you read via ResourceManager which in turn contains that exe. After that you can call .ExecuteAssemblyByName()

Answer (score 3):

You can add an exe as an embedded resource (just right click on a folder in the Solution explorer, Add Existing Item, then get properties on it and set it to be Embedded Resource). However, you may not be able to easily execute it in place - you'll need to save it to disk and then execute it (which doesn't solve your stated problem of having to ShellExecute the .exe file, but does solve the problem of having to ship more than one file to the end user).

If you have the source code, then you'll be able to repackage the exe as a dll, or integrate it directly into your program code.

Answer (score 1):

If the exe is a .NET assembly, you could use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630/) to merge the exe into your main assembly. You can then invoke the code in the exe directly.